# What does "partial credit" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I answer a question, get a reply:

> Thanks! But I can't give this answer partial credit.

I do not understand the `partial credit` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you complete an assignment, problem, task, etc in school, you are usually awarded *points, marks, etc*. In simple terms, you can regard these points as *credit*. There are four expressions dealing with credit that I can think of:

> 1. Full credit
> 2. Partial credit
> 3. Half credit
> 4. No credit

Full credit means you get 100% of the points, or full marks. No credit means you get 0 points, marks, etc. Half credit means you get half of the points. *Partial credit* means you get somewhere between 0 and 100 (exclusive) points. How much you get depends on the grading scheme or the grader's judgement.

Sometimes, there is no point scheme and the credit scheme above is used. In such a case, *partial credit* is unclear but still means between full and no credit.

So in your example, it means that you cannot even receive some credit, or some points, for your answer. It means you get zero credit, or zero points.

As a side note, I'm not sure why, but you cannot say *I got 75 credits on the last test*, for example, at least in AmE. You can say *I got 75 points* or *I got a 75*.

Comment: Because you don't get "credits" on a test.  You get "credit", singular, meaning something like "an entry in your favor on an account".